# Can i take a photo of the milky way?

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, shooting-technique

Can I take a picture with a 
Canon EOS1300D with a Canon EF 50 mm f1.8 STM Lens of the milky way?

Thank you.

Comment: You can take a picture of *anything* with a 1300D and an EF 50mm f/1.8 STM lens. You might or might not get the result you are after, but you can always point the camera in that direction and shoot.

Comment: Related: [Stack of 4 seconds exposure photos of Milky Way, how is it done?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/56944/15871)

Comment: @scottbb That other question is talking about much wider angles of view than an APS-C camera with a 50mm lens will give.

Comment: @MichaelClark perhaps, but the answer by Octopus answers the generic question of that title quite well, with "Select a lens", and specifically mentions why anything more than 50mm FF (30mm crop) leads to too narrow of a FoV generally. The answer explains more than just the specific lens mentioned. Put another way, do we really need to maintain the same question for each individual focal length?

Answer (score 2):

Answer effort inline with question...

According to [this review website](https://www.lonelyspeck.com/canon-ef-50mm-f1-8-stm-astrophotography-review/) you certainly can.

General verdict is that its a cheap lens, and not going to be as clear as nicer lenses out there.

The 1300D has a Bulb shutter mode and exposures up to 30 seconds.  Again, a better camera would have less noise on long exposures.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a good combination for the Milky Way. Although I usually like to use an 18 mm lens on a crop sensor camera for the Milky Way, you will get a smaller portion and longer Star trails. I usually shoot at ISO 3200-6400, lens wide open (f1.8 in your case) and mess with the shutter speed 10-30 seconds usually. I stack several images to reduce noise. You could use a lower ISO to reduce noise and a longer shutter speed but you may get unacceptable star trails. The only thing I don’t like about your setup is the long focal length but other than that it is a fine setup for the Milky Way. The Milky Way always needs post processing to bring out the colors otherwise it just looks like a bunch of stars.