# Dark Frames for Long Exposure on a tracker?

Tags: astrophotography, dark-frame-subtraction

I have come across the concept of dark and bias frames for astrophotography recently.

Usually, I exposes my shot for 15+ minutes on a star tracker at ISO=320. I take around 5-8 shots a night and I stack these shots to remove noises.

I want to incorporate dark frames into my workflow.

Which of these will produce the best results?

1. Shoot (15 mins) -> Dark Frame (1 min) -> Shoot (15 mins) -> Dark Frame (1 min) ...
2. Shoot (15 mins) -> Dark Frame (15 mins) -> Shoot (15 mins) -> Dark Frame (15 mins) ....
3. Shoot (15 mins) -> Shoot (15 mins) -> Dark Frame (15 mins) -> Shoot (15 mins) ...
4. Shoot (15 mins) -> Shoot (15 mins) -> Shoot (15 mins) -> Dark Frame (15 mins) -> Shoot (15 mins)...

If time is a limiting factor (milky way is only going to be out for a few hours in my area), what is a practical and realistic option?

Comment: Note that dark frames must be the same settings as light frames! So 1. is not possible. Also, wouldn't it be more practical to make shorter exposures (1-3min) but more? In case one exposure is bad, you still have others

Comment: Longer exposure gives me better SNR right?

Comment: Theoretically yes. But considering that you can take more shorter exposures in the same time, in stacking, the final noise amount should be about the same. It mostly depends on the total exposure time

Comment: At least that is what I think (I am just starting out in astrophotography). I have however observed that many (semi)professional Astrophotographers choose to only have an exposure time of around 2-3 minutes.

Comment: https://www.amateurastrophotography.com/more-short-exposures-or-fewer-long-exposures-which-is-better

Comment: Interesting. In this case, the reason to take shorter exposures is probably just to eliminate possible tracking and shake issues wich become apparent over such a long time as 15 minutes. Another problem/reason might be sensor heating.

Comment: @Jonas noise reduction is proportional to log_2_(dark frames). So each halving of noise floor corresponds to 2, 4, 8, 16, ... dark frames

Comment: @Jonas conversely, for light frames, reducing exposure time requires increase in ISO (assuming wide-open aperture). Assuming tracking, which is happening here, lower ISO light frames stacked together definitely has benefits combined with same-ISO dark frame stack. Note that number of dark frames doesn't need to correspond w/ # light frames. But dark frames should be done at same temperature, and definitely same ISO.

Comment: *"Another problem/reason might be sensor heating."* You would have to wait between shots to let the sensor cool off...

Comment: Related: [Continuous Bursts of Many Short Exposures vs. A Few Long Exposures for Astrophotography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/41848/15871)  and [Longer exposure & lower ISO or shorter exposure & higher ISO - what gives better results when photographing stars?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/40188/15871)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Astrophotography exposure setting for noise reduction](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71305/astrophotography-exposure-setting-for-noise-reduction)

Comment: You may be interested in the second part of this previous answer https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/103158/34085

Answer (score 3):

Shoot (15 minutes) x (However many frames you want) → manually shoot one dark frame (15 minutes). You can take a manual dark frame by putting a lens cap on the lens before taking the shot. You're done.

Now, use a stacking software that allows you to use a single manually shot dark frame to be applied to each frame

If your total shooting session lasts more than an hour or so, you could take a dark frame each hour or so and use each specific dark frame for the images you've taken between when you took the last dark frame and the most recent dark frame. Some stacking software will easily let you do this, others make you work more for it. You might need to create "sub stacks" for the images taken before each dark frame, then stack the separate results of each stack together.

Also, cover the viewfinder if it is a DSLR with an optical viewfinder. Sometimes minute amounts of light can leak around the edges of the mirror when it is up.

If you have a mirrorless camera with an EVF, you do not need to bother covering the EVF.

For more, please see:

[What's the best way to deal with hot/stuck pixels in long exposure night photographs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/65747/15871)
[Why does my Canon 700D take so long processing when I take a long exposure?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/89086/15871)
[Stack of 4 seconds exposure photos of Milky Way, how is it done?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/56944/15871)

Comment: Thank you! Super helpful!